# Adjust UITableViewCell Height and Indentation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Two UITableViewCell related questions:

1. In my custom UITableViewCell I loop through an array (of which I do not know how many objects it holds) and add a UILabel displaying some text for each object in that array.

This means I have to adjust the height of the cell so that these labels fit in. How can I do this?

2. When going into edit mode, I have the cells indent, however I do not want this. I have tried the following:

`cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing = NO;`

and

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return NO;
}
```

Both sadly failed, I have I no idea why. How could I remedy this?

Comment: Not sure about the editing, but: in the tableViewDelegate, use the tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath: method to set heights for different rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can specify the height for every row with the delegate method `[UITableViewDelegate tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:]`.
   Just change what the method returns and the reload your table.
2. This method actually has nothing to do with the indendation of cell content:

   > Asks the delegate whether **the background** of the specified row should be indented while the table view is in editing mode.

You can try to set `indentationWidth` but I never managed to make it work.
Fortunately, it's easy to change everything you want in `[UITableView layoutSubviews]` method.
Example:
`- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;
}`

Comment: The height did the trick! still having trouble with indentation and thought it would be unfair in the same question. Indentation problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934139/remove-uitableviewcell-edit-mode-indentation

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to set

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

For the dynamic height part there are plenty of other answers and a quick google found a tutorial [here](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/)

Comment: I have tried this and sadly all it does it remove the delete button. I want the ability to delete cells, however I don't want them to indent upon entering edit mode.