# Remove UITableViewCell Edit Mode Indentation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a grouped UITableView and when going into edit mode, the cells indent. I need to stop the cells indenting when going into edit mode.

I have tried two things:

```
cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing = NO;
```

and

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return NO;
}
```

Neither of these stop cell indentation upon entering edit mode.

Comment: so what do you want to happen? where do you expect the "delete" sign to show up? or maybe i misunderstanding the question...:/

Comment: The way I format the text and things means without indentation there is still room the any delete icon. Fairly simple, normally when editing, the cells slide in, they indent. I want to press edit so I still see the delete icons, but without the cells indenting.

Comment: interesting...would you mind pasting your new code that worked? curious to see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it the way documentation suggests, quoting `[UITableViewCell willTransitionToState:]`:

> Subclasses of UITableViewCell can implement this method to animate additional changes to a cell when it is changing state. UITableViewCell calls this method whenever a cell transitions between states, such as from a normal state (the default) to editing mode. The custom cell can set up and position any new views that appear with the new state. **The cell then receives a layoutSubviews message** (UIView) in which it can position these new views in their final locations for the new state. Subclasses must always call super when overriding this method.

In other words, you can change the position and size of the `[UITableViewCell contentView]` in `[UITableViewCell layoutSubviews`, to cancel the indendation.

Comment: When I changed the contentView frame in a grouped table, the content of the cell moved, but the border around the cell stayed the same, so it didn't look right.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you were looking for was this:

> - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
>     return NO; }

*Note: maybe this was not available at the time the top answer what's accepted, but as today is the way to go, so for future reference.*